# How to run many animations in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want to run 2 animations one after another. For example:

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
    self.waterView.frame.origin.y = self.height - 300
    self.waterView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-270) // first
    self.waterView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(270) // second
})
```

How can I run the second animation `self.waterView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(270)` directly after `self.waterView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-270)` this one?

I thought about using animation with completion block and call the function there with the second animation. But I doubt, that it's a correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {

        //DO ANIMATION

        }, completion: { finish in

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: 0.4, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {

        //DO 2ND ANIMATION

        }, completion: nil)

    })
```